Position BottomSheetModal to right in react native
Usually BottomSheetModal animates from bottom and has 100% width. I want to reduce the width and that I can achieve with "width" prop added to style of BottomSheetModal and thats working. Now when I reduced the width to 40% the modal sticks to left and reduced the width accordingly. I want to right align the BottomSheetModal having a width of 40%. Is there any way to achieve that with https://ui.gorhom.dev/components/bottom-sheet/modal?
Tried adding style to BottomSheetModal and the wrapping parent component BottomSheetModalProvider but nothing works.

Use marginHorizontal: "20%" instead of width

Tried but didnt work. Instead the style applied for the items inside bottom sheet modal.

Please share your code.

marginHorizontal: "20%" this worked. Thanks a lot.
